# Count occurencies number of special chars in string

Tags: c#, .net, char

I have some special chars declared that way.

```
private static readonly char[] Chars = "…".ToCharArray();
```

Also, I can check if that chars are present in given string like that way.

```
private static bool ContainsSpecialChars(string text)
    {
        return text.IndexOfAny(Chars) >= 0;
    }
```

But I am stuck in counting how many occurencies are in the given string.

**NOTE**: I have array of chars

Comment: change text to char array, use `Count` with predicate which checks if `Chars` contains given char `text.ToCharArray().Count(c => Chars.Contains(c))`

Comment: hmm I don't think if its duplicate of "How would you count occurrences of a string (actually a char) within a string?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *Linq*. For *arbitrary* special `char`s

```
 private static readonly HashSet<char> SpecialChars = new HashSet<char>() {
   //TODO: put all special chars here
   '.', '#', '?',
 };

 ...

 private static bool ContainsSpecialChars(string text) => 
   text != null && text.Any(c => SpecialChars.Contains(c));

 private static int CountSpecialChars(string text) => 
   text?.Count(c => SpecialChars.Contains(c)) ?? 0;
```

If *special char* actually means some kind(s) of *Unicode Category* (say, punctuation) try using `char` static methods:

```
 private static bool ContainsSpecialChars(string text) => 
   text != null && text.Any(c => char.IsPunctuation(c));

 private static int CountSpecialChars(string text) => 
   text?.Count(c => char.IsPunctuation(c)) ?? 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, is it possible to add **out** parameter to the Count method?

Comment: @hoozr: technically, yes, but why should we add `out` parameter into `Count`? What should it return?

Comment: With out I can use this:  `if(CountSpecialChars(string, out int num) >  0) count += num`

Comment: @hoozr: in the current implementation we have `0` if `string` doesn't have special chars; that's why we don't want `num` and `if` at all: `count += CountSpecialChars(string);`. If `string` *doesn't have* special chars we add `0` to `count` which doesn't change anything

Comment: perfect, thanks! Idk, I can't tag your username, its like disapearing when I post comment.

Comment: I think, I was need `char.IsHighSurrogate` static method

Comment: @hoozr: When working with *surrogate* symbols, you may want *normalize* the string, e.g. `text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Count(...)...`, see  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.normalizationform?view=netframework-4.8 for details

Comment: Yes, I am already using normalization with `StringInfo` member.  `var info = new StringInfo(tmp.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Chars.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    if (toCheck.Contains(x))
       charOccur.Add(x, toCheck.ToList<char>().FindAll(word => word == x).Count);
});
```

as per @Selvins Comment you can also change above code to

```
Chars.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
   if (toCheck.Contains(x))
       charOccur.Add(x, toCheck.ToCharArray().Count(c => Chars.Contains(c)));
});
```